# Automate cronjob creation in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, pm2

Lets say I have N separate scripts. Each script does something different and they have to be executed from time to time, so right now we use pm2 cronjobs to manage them.

Im trying to create this CronJobs in Kubernetesso we can move to AWS EKS but I dont know how to manage all the scripts. The only idea that I have is one container for every script and hence one Cronjob for every container. Other solution is to put all scripts in one image and make a .yaml file with all CronJobs definitions, making a very large file which is not ideal nor scalable

There is a better way to manage this situation? Any way to automate Containers or Cronjob creation like iterating on every script?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather have one container and one CronJob resource per script as they will be able to evolve independently. But it depends on how many scripts you have and the technologies behind every script.

Comment: add sources to support your answer.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/ 
Here is the documentation for CronJobs.

As you can see, there is no way to define one CronTab per container. 

As for my answer, it's only a recommendation from practices that I have, so I don't have documentation to support it.

Comment: Currently I created 1 image with all scripts in it and declaring N cronjobs in a yaml file

Comment: My mistake, misunderstood your post. I would rather have one container and one CronJob resource per script as they will be able to evolve independently. But it depends on how many scripts you have and the technologies behind every script.

Comment: @ABWassim put the sources in your answer please, not in comments. thanks!